# How to set cropper width and height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to add an image cropper component to my project, for that using the react-cropper package. But there is a problem that how to add a fixed width and height for cropper box like "width:200px; height:300px;"

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cropper from "react-cropper";
import "cropperjs/dist/cropper.css";
import "./Demo.css";

type Props = {
  LabelName?: string;
};


export const Demo = (props:Props) => {
  const {LabelName} = props;
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [cropData, setCropData] = useState("#");
  const [cropper, setCropper] = useState<any>();
  const onChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let files;
    if (e.dataTransfer) {
      files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    } else if (e.target) {
      files = e.target.files;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      setImage(reader.result as any);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  };

  const getCropData = () => {
    if (typeof cropper !== "undefined") {
      setCropData(cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL());
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
        <br />
        <Cropper
          zoomTo={0.5}
          initialAspectRatio={1}
          preview=".img-preview"
          src={image}
          viewMode={1}
          minCropBoxHeight={10}
          minCropBoxWidth={10}
          background={false}
          responsive={true}
          autoCropArea={1}
          checkOrientation={false}
          onInitialized={(instance) => {
            setCropper(instance);
          }}
          guides={true}
        />
      </div>

      <br style={{ clear: "both" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Now I can change like this,

[image]

[image]

But my requirement is to fix that copper size, Please give me a solution to fix this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Size:

> minCropBoxWidth: 200,
> minCropBoxHeight: 300,

Required aspect ratio:

> aspectRatio: 1 / 1.5,

Block change cropBox:

> cropBoxResizable: false,

Comment: <Cropper
          
          preview=".img-preview"
          src={image}
          viewMode={1}
          minCropBoxWidth={800}
          minCropBoxHeight={200}
          background={false}
          responsive={true}
          autoCropArea={0}
          checkOrientation={false}
          onInitialized={(instance) => {
            setCropper(instance);
          }}
          guides={true}
          cropBoxResizable={false}
        />  When I use it like this, it doesn't work.. and stays in the same state

Comment: I has edited answer, try this

Comment: `aspectRatio={1 / 1.5}` and `cropBoxResizable={false}` is the way to go. It works well on the [demo website](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)